# TCP Java client sending Data to a C++ Server

Tags: java, c++, tcp

I got a Server with a ClientHandle which accepts requests if there are some and i'd like to send data from Java to it. (the C++ client does work without any issues)

I have read the other posts about this but they didnt help me in any way. [Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611205/how-can-i-send-data-from-a-java-client-to-a-c-server),[Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902898/java-client-and-a-c-server-send-and-receive-via-tcp-socket),[Post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950588/strings-and-character-encoding-in-c)

```
bool ClientHandle::getData(std::shared_ptr<std::string> ptr)
{
    int n;
    ptr->clear();

    char size[4];
    n = recv(m_sock, size, sizeof(size), 0);

    //check if retval passed
    if (!checkRetValRecv(n))
        return false;

    //calc how much data
    auto msgLen = atoi(size);
    LOG_INFO << "recv a message with size: " << msgLen;

    //create buffer for the data
    auto buffer = new char[msgLen];

    //read buffer
    n = recv(m_sock, buffer, msgLen, 0);

    //check retval if it passes
    if (!checkRetValRecv(n))
        return false;
    ptr->append(buffer, msgLen);
    LOG_INFO << "Message: " << *ptr;

    delete[] buffer; 
    return true;
}
bool ClientHandle::checkRetValRecv(const int& n)
{
    if (n == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        size_t err = WSAGetLastError();
        if (err == WSAECONNRESET)
        {
            LOG_ERROR << "Failed to recv! Disconnecting from client: " << "Connection reset by peer.";
        }
        else
        {
            LOG_ERROR << "Disconnecting from client. WSAError: " << err;
        }
        m_connected = false;
        return false;
    }

    if (n == 0)
    {
        LOG_INFO << "Client disconnected.";
        m_connected = false;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now i would like to write a Java client for this to send data but i cant even send the size of the incoming data.

```
public class JClient{
    String m_host;
    int m_port;
    Socket m_sock;
    OutputStreamWriter m_out; 
    BufferedReader m_in;

    public JClient(String host, int port)
    {
        m_host = host;
        m_port = port;
    }

    private void connect() throws IOException
    {
        m_sock = new Socket(m_host, m_port);
        m_out = new OutputStreamWriter(m_sock.getOutputStream());
        m_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(m_sock.getInputStream()));
    }

    private void close() throws IOException
    {
        m_sock.close();
    }

    public void send(String json) throws IOException {
        this.connect();
        m_out.write(json.length());
        m_out.flush();
        m_out.write(json);
        m_out.flush();

        //wait for result
        m_in.read();
        this.close();
    }
}
```

If i try to send Data like so:

```
JClient client = new JIMClient("localhost", 6060);
String toSend = "{\"hello\":\"someJson\"}";
try {
    client.send(toSend);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I do not receive anything usefull. `recv a message with size: 0` , `Client disconnected.`

The send method does not work. I already tried other Streams and using a different encoding, which i guess is the reason for this. So the Question is how do i resolve this issue with the encoding here? I'd like to leave the C++ client as it is if possible or get it to some kind of standart.

Comment: Is the problem in the server with the C++ code, or in the client with the Java code? There's usually no need to show working code, just show us the non-working code and tell us what happens when you run it.

Comment: I do receive a 0 as size but sending a 20, I added it a second ago. I think it is a encoding issue since c++ and java do not need to have the same charset encoding or byteorder of the integer which i try to send. I think it is the client since the Server works with a c++ Client which uses the same functions as the server to connect and send data. I do show the working to see how i recv the data from the client. (first size as int and then data block as char)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java code is only sending only  a single character for the length but C++ expects a 4 byte string.  You might try

```
m_out.write(String.format("%4d%s",json.length(),json));
m_out.flush();
```

Comment: Right. After your answer i checked the methods and noticed that the "write int" does only send one byte. Thanks alot. It's working fine now.